# Postgres format() - nodejs pg-format - using with UPDATE

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to update multiple rows at once with Postgres.

This query works

```
    const updateQuery = `
        UPDATE dating.photos
        SET
            ordering = nv.ordering,
            profile = nv.profile
        FROM
                ( VALUES
                        ('ddb73491-b582-4ff5-afb4-e57e31917b03', 4, false),
                        ('9cd57b09-17ff-4b88-b08f-b1ef02ec8c1d', 2, false),
                        ('02d9d7e2-2601-4e6f-b7d4-ddebdbee420d', 3, false),
                        ('5e04ff58-8f85-43f8-a4ca-dfde85da9e6f', 1, true)
                ) AS nv (photoname, ordering, profile)
        WHERE photos.photoname = nv.photoname`
```

I'm now trying to load data into the UPDATE using pg-format so the data is sanitised.

Note: I've seen pg-format (postgres format()) used with SELECT and INSERT. I'm not 100% sure it can be used with UPDATE.

I've try loading an array like this:

```
    const myNestedArray = [
        [
            "ddb73491-b582-4ff5-afb4-e57e31917b03",
            1,
            true
        ],
        [
            "9cd57b09-17ff-4b88-b08f-b1ef02ec8c1d",
            2,
            false
        ]
    ]
```

I've try loading an array like this:

```
    const myNestedArray = [
        (
            "ddb73491-b582-4ff5-afb4-e57e31917b03",
            1,
            true
        ),
        (
            "9cd57b09-17ff-4b88-b08f-b1ef02ec8c1d",
            2,
            false
        )
    ]
```

This is the query I'm using... you can see the %L for the values

```
    // Update Photo Order
    const query = format(
        `
        UPDATE dating.photos 
        SET 
            ordering = nv.ordering,
            profile = nv.profile
        FROM
                ( VALUES %L
                ) AS nv (photoname, ordering, profile)
        WHERE photos.photoname = nv.photoname`,
        myNestedArray
    )
```

I get back the error:

> Ordering Photos Errors: error: column "ordering" is of type smallint but expression is of type text

It appears it not matching up the values to columns correctly.

How can I get this working?

Comment: FYI https://github.com/datalanche/node-pg-format/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with `pg-format`, if it's going to use for formatting nested arrays data that would have a different data type on each value, I think the `pg-format` couldn't handle it